# Let $\left(\mathbb{C}^{n},+, *\right)$ be a triple, where $+: \mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is the ...

Tags: vector-spaces

**Let $\left(\mathbb{C}^{n},+, *\right)$ be a triple, where $+: \mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is the usual vector addition and $*: \mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ are defined as $$
\boldsymbol{x} * \boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{x} \cdot|\boldsymbol{z}|
$$
$
|z|=\sqrt{\bar{z} z} \in \mathbb{R}
$ and $z \in \mathbb C$. Show that the triple is not a vector space.**

my answer: I just used the axioms of a vector space to check. The problem is that all of the axioms hold. I think this might be a trick question?

In case some of the axioms do not hold please tell me why.

Comment: Not all of the axioms hold.

Comment: :) The axiom about addition definitely do. I can not pinpoint one which does. This is not an assignment just an exercise in the textbook.

Comment: Consider $x*(y+z)$.

Comment: @Xenusi Well, obviously the addition axioms hold: the addition is the same as the standard addition on $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is a vector space. The problem is necessarily going to be something to do with the multiplication, since that's the only thing that has changed.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $x * (-1) = x$, but in a vector space you must have $x *(-1) = -x$ = additive inverse of $x$. The same argument applies if you replace $\mathbb C$ by $\mathbb R$.

Comment: so there is two of the conditions which do not hold.